# How do I go down the stairs in time to save the President?

Tags: mr-president

In [Mr.President!](http://store.steampowered.com/app/507010/MrPresident/), the farthest I can jump is 4 meter using X, while the required distance is about 15 meter. [This video](https://youtu.be/4SlJp8aopJg?t=1m35s) appears to start at the second flight of stairs, but from there the bodyguard is able to dive straight at Rump. How does he do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left mouse button launches the bodyguard forward.